# Comparing last modified time and current time and then deleting files and folders

Tags: python, file-io, time

I have a server and I need to delete files and folders from that server that are in a specific folder, I want to delete these every 3 months, I already know how to do that using crontab and python, the thing is, I ONLY want to delete the file or folder if it is 3 months older or more.

The python code I'm using to delete files and folder is this:

```
import os
import shutil
path = '/path/to/folder'

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for f in files:
                os.unlink(os.path.join(root, f))
        for d in dirs:
                shutil.rmtree(os.path.join(root,d))
```

what I want now is to get every file and folder month that it was last modified and compare this to the current month Im in, and then delete it if and only if its 'age' is greater or equal to 3 months.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this is the answer.

Instead of deleting files older than 3 months, I'm deleting files and folders older than 6 months.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os, glob, shutil, time, datetime
path = glob.glob('/home/piratinha/*')
now  = time.time()
now_str = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(now).strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')
print now_str
for f in path:
    if os.stat(f).st_mtime < now - (6 * 30 * 86400):
        if os.path.isfile(f):
            print "Removendo", f
            os.remove(f)
            print "Arquivo Removido"
        else:
            print "Removendo", f
            shutil.rmtree(f)
            print "Pasta Removida"
else:
    print   "Todos os arquivos e pastas sÃ£o mais novos do que 6 meses."

print now_str
```

BR,

RedCode

Answer (score 0):

The normal way to do this on posix is for files:

```
find path -mtime +90 -a -type f -a -exec rm "{}" \;
```

and for folders:

```
find path -mtime +90 -a -type d -a -exec rm -r "{}" \;
```

But of course you need to be careful about any rm -r! If the folders of interest are not nested this is safer:

```
find path -mtime +90 -a -type d -a -exec rmdir "{}" \;
```

In python, shell exec for this. It is not a cross platform pure python solution.